# Using KISSlicer from command line on Linux?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, g-code, slic3r

Is there a way to use KISSlicer from the Linux command line?

Or convert KISSlicer settings/profile to Slic3r/CuraEngine?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you require a PRO license for using the command line interface.

As of version 1.6 the following command line options are implemented:
[image]